# Did soul of Sati talk with Parvati ? Can soul of one's previous birth from heaven talk with body of one's next birth?

Tags: atma, rebirth, parvati, heaven, sati

In [this episode of hindi serial](https://www.voot.com/shows/shrimad-bhagwat-mahapuran/1/801327/a-story-of-true-love-and-sorrow/807276) it is shown that soul of Sati talked with Parvati (who was alive). (Watch from 26:23) Also It was shown that Shiva used to meet and talk with soul of Sati secretly from Parvati.(from 21:20)

How is it possible ? Sati is the previous birth of Parvati. How can she talk with Parvati if she has taken next birth ?
She is herself telling that her soul has taken new birth in her (Parvati). (Watch from 29:50).

How can one's soul talk with one's next birth ?

**Can soul of one's previous birth located in heaven talk with body of one's next birth ?**

Comment: Only lets watch if in India  & the Sling Voot doesn’t have half the mytho content. Like they don’t have Shani show or Shrimad Bhagavad. I hope they make the premium subscription thing globally available soon. Zee5 did that and I get to see their stuffs

Comment: @devibhakt It is available on Telegram. Just Shrimad Bhagwat Mahapuran. Episode number 4.

Comment: Thx I will try find it  @river